# JSONSerilazation not working while parsing JSON object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsjsonserialization, json

I am getting an error while parsing the NSData I got from a server.
I am unable get the NDIctinory.

I am getting the error **"No string key for value in object"**

```
 NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                                       error:&error];
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nsjsonserialization+no+string+key+for+value+in+object+around+character&oq=no+string+key+for+value+in+object+NSjso&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.4393j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Can you post your fuli code?

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed irrelevant thanks.

Comment: Can you post the JSON you receive please

Comment: @KathiravanG 

 I think the above line is enough to convert JSON String to NSDIctinoary.
Are you asking for JSON String?

Comment: Are  you sure the JSON you're parsing is valid ? Could you show us its format?

Comment: Kind of hard to tell you what's wrong if you don't show us the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that in the object (that's what JSON calls a dictionary) there is a key that is not a string, i. e. a number or another object. This is invalid.

From RFC7159, 4:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
>      surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A *name* is a
>      *string*.

Therefore you will have an invalid JSON. Change that, if possible. Aditionally you can post the whole JSON in your Q. (*Not* in a comment to this A.)